# View Controller not dismissing properly

Tags: ios, swift

I'm in the process of implementing a cancel button for one of my view controllers. This view controller can either be shown, or presented modally. The cancel button works fine when the view controller has been shown, but it is not having any effect when the VC has been presented modally. I have a line of code for my cancel button:

```
let isPresentingInAddRoutineMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController
```

This line of code is supposed to distinguish whether the VC has been shown or presented. I got the line from the Apple development website. In the cancel function it then reads:

```
if isPresentingInAddRoutineMode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

According to the website, the variable should be reading true as the VC has been presented modally (The segue in storyboard says present modally). I tried debugging to see if the boolean is returning true, but it is not. I'm very confused by this and would be very grateful if anyone had any ideas what I've done wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: *"This line of code is supposed to distinguish whether the VC has been shown or presented"* - no, that line of code checks to see if `presentingViewController` is a navigation controller or not.

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry that was explained badly by me. The button which presents the view controller modally is embedded in a navigation controller, so the line of code determines if the current view was delivered through the navigation controller (modally) or the other button (shown).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could be of use instead: `isBeingPresented`

From: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2097564-isbeingpresented

Comment: Okay i've tried this in the cancel button function. The debugger is returning false. Do you know why it's presenting false when the view controller is on screen?

Comment: `isBeingPresented` can only be used in one of the `view[Will|Did][Disa|A]ppear` methods.